Angular 19 upgrade issues - jest-preset-angular. Peer dependency failing
I am getting the following error while trying to do npm install after using the angular's ng update command to update my application from angular 18 to 19.
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @angular/compiler-cli@"^18.0.0" from @angular-devkit/build-angular@18.2.12
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular
npm ERR!   peer @angular-devkit/build-angular@">=15.0.0 <19.0.0" from jest-preset-angular@14.3.3
npm ERR!   node_modules/jest-preset-angular
npm ERR!     dev jest-preset-angular@"^14.3.3" from the root project
My Package JSON:
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "jest --detectOpenHandles",
    "test:watch": "jest --watch",
    "test:coverage": "jest --coverage",
    "build:prod": "ng build --configuration production",
    "build:stage": "ng build --configuration stage",
    "build:test": "ng build --configuration test",
    "build:dev": "ng build --configuration development",
    "clean": "rimraf dist && rimraf node_modules",
    "clean:install": "rimraf dist && rimraf node_modules && npm install"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "jest-preset-angular",
    "setupFilesAfterEnv": [
      "<rootDir>/setup.jest.ts"
    ],
    "testPathIgnorePatterns": [
      "<rootDir>/node_modules/",
      "<rootDir>/dist/"
    ],
    "coveragePathIgnorePatterns": [
      "<rootDir>/src/tests/",
      "<rootDir>/src/app/login/",
    
    ],
    "globals": {
      "ts-jest": {
        "tsConfig": "<rootDir>/tsconfig.spec.json",
        "stringifyContentPathRegex": "\\.html$"
      }
    },
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "<rootDir>/node_modules/(?!.*\\.mjs$)"
    ]
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^19.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "^19.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^19.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^19.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^19.0.0",
    "@angular/material": "^19.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^19.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^19.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^19.0.0",
    "bootstrap": "^5.3.3",
    "moment": "^2.30.1",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.46",
    "rxjs": "~7.8.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.15.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/build": "^19.0.2",
    "@angular/cli": "^19.0.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^19.0.0",
    "@types/jest": "^29.5.13",
    "@types/moment-timezone": "^0.5.13",
    "eslint": "^9.9.0",
    "jest": "^29.7.0",
    "jest-preset-angular": "^14.3.3",
    "rimraf": "^6.0.1",
    "typescript": "~5.5.2"
  }
}




Support for v19 hasn't landed yet, at least in a stable version.
But you can already test it by installing jest-preset-angular : 14.4.0-rc.0.

you can now install new version of jest-preset-angular of 14.4.0 and it will work just fine
